# How can I typeset the operator as upright Roman font?

Tags: greek, letters

Journal ask the operator `\Delta` is typeset in upright font. I try `\operatorname{\Delta}`, but it doesn't work and appears to have not use `\operatorname`. But if try `\operatorname{d}` it works.

Comment: Could you show us what it should look like? `\Delta` does not produce an slanted symbol.

Comment: I believe $\Delta$ gives an equilateral triangle that is upright, is not it?

Comment: Hi, @ Werner. I write it as $\Delta$ or in an equation environment. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18885/delta-like-symbol-in-latex, I want the upright \Delta without the arrow above.

Comment: Hi, @Chou. In my document, it looks italic. Please go to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18885/delta-like-symbol-in-latex. What I want is the second one without arrow but what I got is the first one...

Comment: Are you using Amsart? I am using it and the result is exactly what I asserted and also what you want? Is it possible for you to use Amsart instead? @Ixy

Comment: Well, I have checked that  (with Windows 7, MikTex 2.9, Texstudio) the command \Delta gives an equilateral triangle whether in Amsart or in Article. :)

Comment: Show your preamble if possible, which would help in troubleshooting.

Comment: \increment should always give it upright, even if you use italic greek upper case letters

Comment: @ Chou, Thanks. The preamble is
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} and I am using WinEdt 7.0 and compile with PDFTeXify.

Comment: Make sure you are not using `\varDelta`

Comment: @lxy -- what `\documentclass` are you using?  (actually, this is part of your preamble, which includes everything from that line up until `\begin{document}`.)

Answer (score 2):

By default, plain TeX and LaTeX typeset the Greek capital letters in roman upright (following the established anglo-american tradition in mathematical typesetting).

So, just typing `$\Delta$` gives you an upright capital Greek Delta.

You have to add some packages to change this behaviour. Comment out your packages until you have found the culprit.

P.S. Note that there is a difference between `$\Delta$` and `$\bigtriangleup$`.