# How to get a strongly slanted Delta

Tags: math-mode, symbols, slanted

Early 20th century texts on calculus of variations use a very strongly slanted Delta. A sample is below. It is much more slanted than the  `\mathit{\Delta}` discussed in [Delta-like symbol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18885/delta-like-symbol-in-latex), and more slanted than in [A particular big Delta](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/a-particular-big-delta)

The specific difference is that I want the upper vertex farther to the right than the bottom right one.

How can I match this in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the accepted answer to that question is irrelevant to me, but your answer to it does answer my question.

Comment: This question has been closed, but the `stix` font (Also available in OpenType as XITS Math) a slanted `\mathit{\Delta}` that looks much like this. It is, however, a relatively thick font. In `unicode-math`, you can also `\setmathfont` with the `range=\mitDelta` and `FakeSlant` options.

Comment: Cambria Math has an even more slanted `\mitDelta`, and might be a better match for the weight of your other fonts. So, perhaps `\setmathfont[range=\mitDelta, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Cambria Math}` after your primary `\setmathfont`.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: The real answer to this question is does this symbol exist somewhere in a math font. That I do not know. But, just as a proof of concept, you could create the symbol using Ti*k*Z. Whether this is a good idea and how this fits with your math font of choice is another matter.

I've called the symbol `\SDelta` and it is scaled using `scalerel` to match the size of `\Delta`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\SDelta}{\scalerel*{%
\tikz{\draw (0.2,0) coordinate (RBASE) --(0,0) coordinate (LBASE) --++(45:0.32) coordinate (TOP) --cycle;
\draw [line width=0.25mm] ([xshift=-0.01cm]RBASE)--([xshift=-0.01cm,yshift=-0.015cm]TOP);
\draw  ([yshift=0.005cm]RBASE)--([yshift=0.005cm]LBASE);
}}{\Delta}}

\begin{document}
\[
\SDelta J = \int_{t_0}^t \SDelta F \, \mathrm{d}t 
\]
\[\scriptstyle
\SDelta J = \int_{t_0}^t \SDelta F \, \mathrm{d}t 
\]
\[
\Delta J = \int_{t_0}^t \Delta F \, \mathrm{d}t 
\]
\[\scriptstyle
\Delta J = \int_{t_0}^t \Delta F \, \mathrm{d}t 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this since all my documents use TiKZ anyway.

Comment: Possibly consider wrapping in `\mathord{}` so that it has the same spacing as `\Delta`? Is that necessary?

Comment: The recent comments show how to get the character I want by a simple font choice, more practical than using TiKZ for this.